# When does NetworkStream.Read wait for more data?

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, tcp, networkstream

When [`NetworkStream.Read(buffer,offset,size)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) is called and no data is currently available, it blocks until at least one byte has been received, or the stream is closed.

Does the implementation of `NetworkStream.Read()` by Microsoft *always* return as soon as the first tcp packet has been received, or if not, in which cases will it wait for further data?

In other words, when one only one byte is sent, will a `Read()` with a buffer of size 1 on average take the same time as a `Read()`with a larger buffer size?

When only one byte is sent, can `NetworkStream.Read(buffer,0,1)` return faster than `NetworkStream.Read(buffer,0,1024)`?

Such as when the sender does not send the TCP push bit (PSH)?

I found conflicting information regarding this. In particular I found [this quote](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcp-push-flag.html):

> If in a situation where the TCP layer is forced, and low latency is
>   crucial, then the receiving application should recv() into a **small**
>   **buffer to improve latency**. The receive buffer (provided by the
>   receiving application) should not be confused with the receive window
>   (provided by the receiving TCP layer).

and [this remark](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741688(v=vs.85).aspx) in the documentation for WSARecv, which I believe is the underlying windows api call used by `NetworkStream.Read()`:

> In the case of TCP, this refers to the case of incoming TCP segments
>   being placed into the receive request data buffer where none of the
>   TCP segments indicated a PUSH bit value of 1. In this case, TCP **may**
>   **hold the partially filled receive request a little longer** to allow the
>   remainder of the data to arrive with a TCP segment that has the PUSH
>   bit set to 1.

So is my conclusion about tcp packets with missing push bit correct?

If so, what is the maximum delay I can expect?

And are there other cases where a Read() may be delayed further depending on buffer size?

Comment: The only _guarantee_ you have is that provided by the API requirements: the call won't complete until some data is available. What any given implementation does with this requirement is undefined beyond that, but as you've already seen, at least in _some_ cases, you may wait longer than "any data is available". Note that exact behavior depends not just on the platform on which your code is running, but behavior at the remote endpoint as well. _"I want to get any arriving bytes as fast as possible"_ -- first you need to define "fast" more precisely. Latency != throughput.

Comment: Thanks for your input; I have attempted to clarify my question and removed subjective phrasing. But I have actually not already seen whether in some cases I may wait longer; all I found were the two quotes above, and I am not at all certain whether I am interpreting them correctly.

Comment: Interpreting statements (or validating interpretations of others) made by others is "primarily opinion based". Questions of the form _"is there any situation"_ are inherently "too broad". Please restrict your question to a _specific_, practical, answerable question about programming. See [ask], https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, and other advice at https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.

Comment: Your attempts to narrow the scope of your question are unlikely to succeed. The "implementation of `NetworkStream.Read()`" is very basic and doesn't have anything to do with your question; it simply delegates to the underlying network layer software, which has all of the broad possibilities of behavior that make this question "too broad" to start with. It doesn't matter how much polish you put on the question...it very likely will remain fundamentally as it was at the outset...

Comment: Note also: if the remote endpoint application layer sends just one byte, that byte will likely be consolidated with other bytes. Latency will be added at that end, and you can't do anything about it. If you convince the other end to disable Nagle's algorithm, that will reduce latency, but it is better to move to UDP in that case.